# OData response is leaving primitive values on root level of json

Tags: c#, serialization, odata

I'm implementing OData into a `GET` call to expand a single object type from a larger return object to reduce serialization costs.  Unfortunately, `ODataQueryOptions` isn't returning the serialized object in the format I would expect.  Namely, it leaves any primitive typed values that are defined at the "root" level of the object (when serialized) when I didn't specify them in the expand.

Server side code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RetrieveDocument(int id, ODataQueryOptions<Contract.EstimateDocument> oDataQuery)
    {
        var cacheKey = EstimateDocumentCacheKeyGenerator.GetCacheKeyForEstimateDocument(id, CurrentUserSession.UserOrgCode, oDataQuery.RawValues.Filter, oDataQuery.RawValues.Expand);
        string serializedEstimateDocument;

        if (!_serializedEstimateDocumentCache.TryGet(cacheKey, out serializedEstimateDocument))
        {
            var estimateDocument = _estimateDocumentService.RetrieveDocument(CurrentUserSession, id);
            if (oDataQuery.SelectExpand != null||
                oDataQuery.Filter != null)
            {
                IQueryable<Contract.EstimateDocument> estimateDocumentQueryable =
                    new List<Contract.EstimateDocument>() {estimateDocument}.AsQueryable();
                var result = oDataQuery.ApplyTo(estimateDocumentQueryable);
                serializedEstimateDocument = CacheResponseObject(result, cacheKey);
            }
            else
            {
                serializedEstimateDocument = CacheResponseObject(estimateDocument, cacheKey);
            }
        }

        var responseMessage = CreateMessage(serializedEstimateDocument, HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //LogApiCall(id, responseMessage);
        return responseMessage;
    }
```

What I get back when I expand upon psudo-object type:

```
[{
    "psudoObject" : { /*contents*/ },
    "primitive1": value1,
    "primitive2": value2,
    "primitive3": value3
    etc...
}]
```

Expected:

```
[{
    "psudoObject": { /*contents*/ }
}]
```

Is there an OData setting I can alter to get my expected result?  Failing that, is there a way to remove those objects that doesn't involve altering the serialized object string?